# Seek for TextFile

Tags: delphi, text-files

I'm working with very large text files, 2GB and more. I would like to have a Seek() like function. Has anyone done something like that? Loading to TStringList is out of the question. Also working with untyped file as well. For now I'm using readLn, but that lasts too long. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is supposed the seek function will do, seek for a particular offset in bytes? seek for a line number? or what?

Comment: When loading 2,5 GB in memory, I load it by pages, 300000 lines at once. I create the index and move to the next page. But that gives me only sequential access, and I would like a direct access.

Comment: for such huge files, since Memory Mapped files won't always work - so your loading by pages is the best approach.

Comment: Why would this give you sequential access??? You have an index. Use Seek to positions defined by the index.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Map the file into memory (CreateFileMapping/MapViewOfFile) by pieces, then scan the mapped memory and build an index - the list of positions of each line beginnings. Then your seek operation will be performed by getting position of Nth line in the file and seeking to this position. Use TFileStream then to perform random access to the file or, if you only read the file, you can use file mappings for random access as well - this might be even faster than using TFileStream in parallel to file mapping.

Comment: How's mapping the file to memory going to help with initial scanning? I doubt it's faster then block-by-block sequential reading (ie: set up an buffer that's an multiple of your file system's block size and read to that)

Comment: @Cosmin A bit less of operations - with MapViewOfFile you get a pointer which you can immediately pass somewhere. With ReadFile you have a buffer, which you pass to ReadFile API, which calls NtReadFile, which calls ZwReadFile, which issues an IRP which travels the complete driver stack. The difference is minimal, yet it exists.

Comment: @Cosmin: MMF is MUCH faster than File I/O, especially for sequential block reading.  In one of my own apps, when reading multi-GB files using both techniques, MMF can finish in under a minute, where File I/O can take several minutes.

Comment: -1 because memory mapping won't work with such huge files, in some cases. Or you'll have to close the current MapViewOfFile then reopen it for a "window" of some MB. So it's not a better solution than your sequential one.

Comment: @A.Bouchez Did you see "by pieces" phrase?

Comment: @Eugene: I wrote that MapViewOffile will be done then closed. Using a memory mapping file "by piece" or reading some fixed-size buffer (like 64 MB) is as fast as reading 300000 lines at once as Mihaela did. And perhaps even less efficient, because virtual mapping will call in all cases the file reading, and will have to find some continuous block of memory, whereas the fixed 64 MB buffer will be pre-allocated.

Comment: @A.Bouchez I would like to welcome you to talk about things which you have expertise in.

Comment: @Eugene I was talking about the fact that when a page fault occurs during usage of a memory mapped file, it will indeed read it from disk. If you read a file which is bigger than the available RAM in a non sequential order, you'll have a lot of page faults. In this case, direct reading in a buffer could make sense. A page fault costs - see http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2004-June/050371.html

Comment: @A.Bouchez *seeking* the file (SetFilePointer operation) requires a request to travel all the long way from Win32 API through native API and down to file system drivers. With pointers in memory this operation is faster. To summarize: MMFs are not a magic bullet but with clever design they offer better performance than file API. Next, important part of the question and the answer was how to find positions of lines. For this one should build an index first, and this is important - many people miss the idea of index when they have the task to process text files randomly.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for the arguments! You're right: SetFilePointer triggers a sysenter, therefore a kernel mode switch. A page fault will sometimes have bigger overhead (see my link). If you process a 2 GB file randomly, you'll have to call UnmapViewOfFile() then MapViewOfFile() because you'll be short of noncontiguous memory address (at least in 32 Windows): if you read randomly the first then the last line, memory map will be slower than SetFilePosition+ReadFile. About random access of Text file, you can also use the TextSeek() function I wrote below, then just a ReadLn() to go to the next line.

Comment: @A.Bouchez I have little time for arguing, but I know how the given task can be implemented so that MMF will give the performance boost over file access. If you don't know or don't understand this, you can order our custom services and we'll write such code for you at our regular rate.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for arguing for free! Even if I don't have your expertise, I certainly know that there is always a walk-around. I don't need to hire you for that: I'd rather spend my free time on this, and distribute the solution for free. I'm using memory mapped files in some of our solutions. See for instance http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=1055#p1055 about how we added 1,000,000 multi-fields records in a memory-mapped based database, in 800 ms. A true FOSS solution. Open source made it even stronger (I have a lot of feedback in the forum or by email). Enjoy your day!

Answer (score 3):

Try [GpHugeFile](http://gp.17slon.com/gp/gphugefile.htm).

> Encapsulation of Windows file-handling routines that allows work with >2GB files.
>
> Included is support for non-buffered access (FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING) and buffering for sequentially accessed files. Includes also stream wrapper class.

Answer (score 2):

You set some pretty hard borderconditions.

The only thing I can imagine is to try to get the handle from the textfile, and use win32 functions to seek directly. Beware of textfile caching though.

If large codebases using writeln/readln are the reason, implementing your own textfile driver that allows it (or simplifies caching) might be the solution.

Free Pascal has a getfilehandle function for this purpose, to retrieve the OS handle from textfile/tfilerec files. I don't know what recent Delphi's add in this department.

Answer (score 2):

If you need line-level granularity instead of byte-level, there is absolutely no way to avoid reading through the entire file at least once in order to find the end of line markers (LF or CRLF, depending on your environment.) This is a hard limit - you can't know in advance where your end of line is going to be.

After building the end of line to byte offset index you could conceivably cache it on-disk and use a heuristic a la "last modified time" to check whether the index needs to be regenerated (you need a heuristic because you can't ensure that the file contents hasn't changed except by reading through it, and then you might as well rebuild the index since you'll be I/O bound anyway.)

As suggested by others, the underlying mechanism will have to be CreateFileMapping / CreateViewOfFile (or mmap under POSIX.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to change the current position in a TText file:

```
function TextSeek(var f: Text; position: Int64): boolean;
var pos64: Int64Rec absolute position;
    resHi: cardinal;
begin
  result := false;
  with TTextRec(f) do
  begin
    if mode<>fmInput then
      exit;
    resHi := pos64.Hi;
    if (SetFilePointer(handle,pos64.Lo,@resHi,FILE_BEGIN)<>pos64.Lo) or
       (resHi<>pos64.Hi) then
      exit;
    BufEnd := 0; // flush internal reading buffer
    BufPos := 0;
    result := true; // success
  end;
end;
```

It will return true on success, false on error (invalid position of file not opened).

If you want to have fast access, ensure that you have set {$I-} and check IOResult by hand, and have called System.SetTextBuffer() with some buffer (1 KB up to 64 KB could make sense).